# unsupported address error when trying to access page on specific port in a LAN

Tags: windows-phone-8

when I try to access a page on my IIS Express in a LAN (e.g. 192.168.1.123:3766/Host/MyPage.aspx) from my HTC 8S with Windows Phone 8 I get an error message that says "Unsupported address Internet Explorer Mobile doesn't support this type of address and can't display this page.

Is it possible to get this to work and if so how?

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the protocol. Try `http://192.168.1.123:3766/Host/MyPage.aspx`.

You will also need to follow the instructions here to make sure that your IIS Express is serving up on a port which your phone can see.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx

In particular follow this section:

> **Quick solution with IIS Express**
>
> 1. Create a firewall exception to allow HTTP requests through the firewall on the port that IIS Express is using.
> 2. Get the IP address of the development computer, if necessary, by running ipconfig.
> 3. Find the IIS Express configuration file, applicationhost.config, in the folder %USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config. The USERPROFILE environment variable typically has a value of C:\Users\.
> 4. Open applicationhost.config with Notepad or another text editor and make the following changes.
>
>    a. Find the site element for the web service, WebServiceForTesting.
>
>    b. If you don’t see the site element for the web service, you have to deploy the service at least one time to create the element.
>
>    c. Within the bindings section of the site element, copy the binding element and paste a copy directly below the existing binding element to create a second binding.
>
>    d. In the new binding element, replace localhost with the computer’s IP address.
> 5. Save the changes.
> 6. Run Visual Studio as administrator and open the Visual Studio solution.

And beware of:

> **Important Note:**
>   On a corporate domain, the emulator appears as a separate network device that is not joined to the domain. As a result, you may also have to get an exception from your IT department before the emulator can connect to services that are running on the domain-joined development computer.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but now I get the error message "We're having trouble displaying this page We're having trouble with the page you're trying to reach and can't open it at the moment. Try the following: -Refresh the page or try again later." Is it possible that the port is causing the trouble?

Comment: The problem I had was that I used the Visual Studio Development Server instead of my IIS and that did not work because you cannot access the Development Server from another Device. I changed my project and now it works.